# Is there a way to get a listing of all available URL API parameters from a server?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working with a server that has a kind of mock-API for integrating widgets onto your webpage. They use URLs to get info from the server using simple parameters in the URL, for example:`//lgapi.libapps.com/widgets.php?site_id=1234&widget_type=7&widget_embed_type=2&etc=etc`

Is there a way I can request a full listing of all parameters doing something simple like, `//lgapi.libapps.com/widgets.php?parameters`? Or by calling some magic function that can return a list of all parameters, or is my only option to contact the server and request documentation?

Comment: For this to be possible the ability to request a list of available parameters would have to be included in the API itself; I don't think it's possible to do this automatically.

Comment: there is wsdl, but not too many folks use it anymore. i'm afraid you'll need to find docs...

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic feature in all web servers or of the HTTP protocol that gives you a list of all parameters it accepts.

For such a feature to exist, it would have to be a specific endpoint that a particular API implements on that specific server which was specific to that particular service and you'd have to consult their own documentation to know what that endpoint was.

Such a capability did exist in some forms of the early SOAP web services that Microsoft (and some others) proposed (the ability to query an interface), but the overall proposal was so much more complicated than simple REST URLs that it pretty much went be the way-side as a commonly used standard.

So, for most services, the answer is to "consult the developer documentation for the particular web site" or "examine the network trace of a client that is already using the service to see what it is doing".

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, there is not an inbuilt way into the HTTP protocol for requesting available parameters to a web address.**

The best option would be for you to contact the server's owners, or looking on their website. Most API services have a form of API documentation. For an example of what you are looking for, here is [Twitter's API Documentation Homepage](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation).

I sincerely hope that this helps you, and let me know if there's anything else I can do to help you. Good luck with your project!